# Proof: Generalized Version Of The Basic Counting Principle

Tags: combinatorics

> **The Generalized Basic Principle Of Counting**
>
> If $r$ experiments that are to be performed are such that the first one may result in any of $n_1$ possible outcomes; and if, for each of these $n_1$ possible outcomes, there are $n_2$ possible outcomes of the second experiment; and if, for each of the possible outcomes of the first two experiments, there are $n_3$ possible outcomes of the third experiment; and if ..., then there is a total of $n_1\cdot n_2\cdot...\cdot n_r$ possible outcomes of the $r$ experiments.

---

I want to prove the generalized version of the Basic Principle Of Counting by recursively applying the Basic Principle Of Counting.

Now, the proof I have for the Basic Principle Of Counting is one where all the possible outcomes of two experiments are enumerated, where the first experiment can result in any of $m$ possible outcomes, and the second experiment can result in any of n possible outcomes: $$(1,1),(1,2),...,(1,n)$$ $$(2,1),(2,2),...,(2,n)$$
$$|\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,|\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,|$$ $$(m,1),(m,2),...,(m,n)$$

where we say that the outcome is $(i,j)$ if experiment 1 results in its $i$th possible outcome and experiment 2 then results in its $j$th possible outcome. Hence, the set of possible outcomes consists of $m$ rows, each containing $n$ elements. This proves the Basic Principle of Counting.

---

Now I want to prove the generalized version of the Basic Principle of Counting by recursively applying the Basic Principle of Counting, how would I go about that?

For me it seems sufficient to say that for every $(i,j,k,...,n)$ where experiment $e_n$ results in its $n$th possible outcome, .... , experiment $e_k$ results in its $k$th possible outcome, experiment $e_j$ results in its $j$th possible outcome, experiment $e_i$ results in its $i$th possible outcome. Where $e_i$ is outcome of a possible $n_i$ outcomes of experiment 1, $e_j$ is outcome of a possible $n_j$ outcomes of experiment 2, $e_k$ is outcome of a possible $n_k$ outcomes of experiment 3,...,$e_n$ is outcome of a possible $n_n$ outcomes of the last experiment.

Hence, resulting in a total of $n_i\cdot n_j\cdot n_k \cdot ...\cdot n_n$ possible outcomes.

---

However this is not familiar grounds for me and I'm sure there's a better way to go about proving using that method.

Give me any hints and suggestions you have.

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with naive set theory, which I'm sure you are at this point, this may help:

Let $\{E_i\}_{i=1}^r$ denote our $r$ experiments and the sets $\{S_i\}_{i=1}^r$ denote the possible outcomes of each experiment respectively. Then $n(S_i)=n_i$ for $1\leq i \leq r$, where $n(S_i)$ denotes the number of elements in $i^{th}$ set. Now, looking at all of the possible outcomes of each experiment together, we will obtain the cartesian product 
$$A=S_1\cdot S_2 \cdot\cdot\cdot S_r$$
$$\implies n(A)=n(S_1)\cdot n(S_2) \cdot\cdot\cdot n(S_r)=n_1\cdot n_2\cdot\cdot\cdot n_r$$
and our result is proven (since the cardinality of a cartesian product will result in the product of the cardinalities of the each crossed set individually i.e $n(A \times B)=n(A)\cdot n(B)$).